# How can we check if video blured or not with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, video-streaming

Is there any way to check whether video is displayed as blurred while running, I am automating the video player, I want to check whether video is blurred or not.
I am using javascript for calling player events.

```
js.executeScript("window.frames['player_Id'].document.getElementById('player123').play()");
js.executeScript("window.frames['player_Id'].document.getElementById('player123').pause()");
```

Can this be achieved with selenium or do we need to use any other library?

Comment: Selenium can operate on web elements, so if you are able to get information from html or css (eg class attribute) you can do it using selenium. If you want to exactly check the video you have to use another tool (I dont know what tool, some image comparison I think)

Comment: What do you mean by blurred ? Is the resolution too low or is there some dark div is covering the video (for example when you move mouse over the video) ?

Comment: YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbLNm3LsMaw can give you a starting point here. Another case study from TCS http://www.tataelxsi.com/services/product-engineering-rd/casestudies/video-test-automation.html is going to help. You should be looking for how to get "pixel level information" from a player and then ASSERTs with your test standards.

Comment: i mean if the resolution displayed of video is very low ( i.e. blurred)